# W3C XML sample file produces "there are multiple root elements. line 4. position 9." error

Tags: xml

So I am urged to test sample xml files out before creating one myself and I stumble upon this error when I try to validate the first sample xml file

Here's the sample xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns ="http://my-company.com/namespace" targetNamespace="http://my-company.com/namespace" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault ="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
       <xs:element name="Company">
                <xs:annotation> 
                <xs:documentation>Root element</xs:documentation> 
                </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:complexType>  
                            <xs:sequence>  
                                <xs:element name="Address"/>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:element name="Person"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                        <xs:complexType> 
                                            <xs:sequence> 
                                                <xs:element name="First"  type="xs:string"/> 
                                                <xs:element name="Last" type="xs:string"/> 
                                                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Title"  type="xs:string"/> 
                                                <xs:element name="PhoneExt"> 
                                                <xs:simpleType> 
                                                <xs:restriction  base="xs:integer"> 
                                                <xs:maxInclusive value ="99"/> 
                                                </xs:restriction> 
                                                </xs:simpleType> 
                                            </xs:element> 
                                            <xs:element name="Email"  type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:sequence>  
                        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Where did you get this "sample file" from? The title of your post suggests it's published by W3C, is that correct, and if so where?

Comment: Oh then I misused the word 'sample', it was submitted as a part of a tutorial by my tutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea where you got that from but

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns ="http://my-company.com/namespace" targetNamespace="http://my-company.com/namespace" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault ="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

change it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns ="http://my-company.com/namespace" targetNamespace="http://my-company.com/namespace" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault ="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
```

ie get rid of the last /

it's closing the schema node off, but to follow the rules everything else has to be inside the root node.

Comment: Oh I see, I had it the way you provided before but I kept getting the error: 
"The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not supported in this context." - Line 11. Position 38.

"The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not supported in this context." - Line 19. Position 42.

Which is pointing at "<xs:complexType>"

Comment: Never looked that far. Without the / it's well formed, but it's not valid against the xsd it's referencing. Correct is open tag follwed by close tag and such, valid is follow the rules in the schema. To make this snippet valid you need to rip out those  complexType start and end nodes it doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it after going over what is allowed and what isn't.